# C++: map operation on a list of template type

Tags: c++, templates

I have 2 classes without any functions:

```
template<class Type>
class Core {};

template<class... ClassType>
class Base {
};
```

I'm hoping to implement a `convert()` function within `Base` that can convert a `Base<int, double>` into `Base<Core<int>, Core<double>>`, like:

```
    Base<int, double> base0;
    Base<Core<int>, Core<double>> target0 = base0.convert();

    Base<char, bool, double> base1;
    Base<Core<char>, Core<bool>, Core<double>> target1 = base1.convert();
```

It is basically a map function on a list of type parameter. that convert any
`Base<x, y, z...>` into `Base<Core<x>, Core<y>, Core<z>...>`. How do I implement such function?

[live code](https://onlinegdb.com/rLu41OolC)

Comment: `auto convert() { return Base< Core<ClassType>... > {}; }` [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WE6cdfao7)

Comment: @rafix07 Might post an answer? I want to accept this solution.